# WebGrid header doesn't change background color using CSS - ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, styling, webgrid

I have a simple problem: the WebGrid header doesn't change it's background color. Every other element of it responds to a change in the CSS: the footer, the alternating columns... The only element that doesn't respond to a change in the CSS property background-color or background is the header. Anyone has stumbled with this problem?

Here is the CSS I'm using:

```
.webgrid-header
{   
   background-color: #F4F4F4;
   padding: 6px 5px;
   text-align: center;
   height: 40px;

   border-bottom: 2px solid #959595;
   border-top: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
   border-left: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
   border-right: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

And, for instance, I'll put another one that is working:

```
.webgrid-alternating-row
{
    background-color: #F4F4F4;
    height: 30px;    
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d2d2d2;
    border-left: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-right: 2px solid #CCCCCC;
}
```

I put the `headerStyle: "webgrid-header"` in the `GetHtml` method in the View. Can anyone help me? (and sorry for my English!)

Comment: do the `padding` `text-align` `height` and the `border` styles work on `.webgrid-header`? I'm trying to understand whether the problem lies with the background-color or with the name of the class.

Comment: Yes, they all work. Just `background-color` and `background` don't work. Crazy! :(

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your table cells have their own backgrounds which are being drawn over the background of the row.

Comment: I don't understand... So why does the `background-color` work in the `.webgrid-alternating-row`? The background there changes its color; Just the header does not!

Comment: Hmmm... Look at the elements in Firebug and see where the background coems from

Comment: PERFECT! Didn't know Firebug yet - just started web developing now! :) The problem was that the `background-color` in CSS property `table th` was "dominating" the one in `.webgrid-header`. Thank you very much!

Comment: -1 This isnt the correct answer as it is not true and therefore cannot be the answer to the OP. Have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/r3nMW/ `tr` does in fact have a background property that can be set by css.

Answer (score 1):

I was slightly confused by the above answer and comments.

For the sake of the WebGrid css, it is necessary that the `webgrid-header` specifies a `th` to set the background colour, such as:

```
.webgrid-header th
{
    background-color: #666;
}
```

See this post - http://www.websitesorcery.com/post/2012/03/12/Styling-the-ASPNET-MVC-WebGrid.aspx

Comment: Yeah, it's right - but there were another "background-color" in "th" that was dominating the one in webgrid. The answer is in fact the idea of using the Firebug tool to discover which CSS property is actually running.

Comment: Maybe is it the case to write another answer to be more clear?

Comment: @pfeds is correct, you need to add a ".webgrid-header th" to the css to override the "table th".  I corrected the missing "." in his original answer (see the syntax in the article he linked to).  For IE9 users, pressing F12 opens up Developer Tools which has basically the same functionality as Firebug in FireFox.

Comment: To access Developer Tools in Chrome press Ctrl+Shift+I.  I would guess that Safari and Opera have similar tools but I don't know offhand.